# How does one use curl to crawl a website but with a different session each time?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, curl, libcurl

How does one use curl to crawl a website but with a different session each time? Basically, I would like to visit a page using curl, but with a new session every time.

Basically the web app should think each curl visit is a different user.

Is such a thing possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, http is stateless and there is no such thing (in the http protocol itself) as a session.

There is a Rails session, which I believe is managed with cookies.  (At least I was in Rails 2.x.)  As long as you don't send a cookie, it should think it's a new Rails session.

The web server may be tracking sessions, or some utility to track visits and hits.  This is done when a request is from the same IP address in a given window of time.  For these sessions, you will not be able to use curl to be a different visit from before.